# Problem on loading caster wheel of tutorial

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear Gazebo Users,
I am a newbie user of Gazebo. Following the tutorial described in http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&ver=1.9%2B&cat=build_robot, I get error when I try to add caster element.
This is what I get:

Warning [parser.cc:713] XML Element[collision], child of element[model] not defined in SDF. Ignoring[collision]. You may have an incorrect SDF file, or an sdformat version that doesn't support this element.
Warning [parser.cc:713] XML Element[visual], child of element[model] not defined in SDF. Ignoring[visual]. You may have an incorrect SDF file, or an sdformat version that doesn't support this element.

Thank you for your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8199/problem-on-loading-caster-wheel-of-tutorial/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1134/rahndall/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems like you're trying to put `<visual>` and `<collision>` elements directly inside `<model>`. Make sure you put them into `<link>` like this:

```
<model ...>
  <link ...>
    <visual ...> ... </visual>
    <collision ...> ... </collision>
  </link>
</model>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0